# Knowing when I need the obtuse angle from a circle

Tags: trigonometry, angle

Essentially i'm building a city building game, and for the road tool, I create these cubic Bezier curves. 
The curves need to form the arcs of circles, meaning they are restricted to 90 degree angles for them to be accurate. This isn't relevant to the question but it gives some background information on what i'm trying to achieve.
When the user drags to build the road, you have a start point, and an end point where the mouse currently is. The user also creates an exit angle from the start point, which I use to calculate a gradient (also the tangent gradient of the start point.) Using this information and some basic trig, I can find the centre of the circle.
Problem is that I now need to know the angle between the start point and the end point, from the centre. 
I can use the cosine formula to get this angle, however it only works for acute triangles. If the user is dragging far enough around the circle, the road will be greater than 180 degrees and the angle from the start point to the end point will be obtuse. 
I've attached a paint diagram of what i'm trying to achieve, hopefully you understand what I'm after. :)
[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2vKl.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the start vector is $v = (x, y)$. Compute a new vector $w = (-y, x)$. This will be 90 degrees counterclockwise from $v$. (Pretty cool, eh?)

Now take the vector $u$ whose angle from $v$ you want to find (measure CCW, from 0). Compute
$$
c = u \cdot v \\
s = u \cdot w,
$$
where both of those denote the dot-product of vectors, 
and then set
$$
\theta = atan2(s, c)
$$
(with the small proviso that in your programming language, you may want to use atan2(c, s), because there's always someone willing to screw with a standard, even if it is a stupid standard.)

The result will be an angle between $-\pi$ and $\pi$ (in almost every language). If the vector $u$ happens to be the zero vector, you'll probably still get $\theta = 0$, which isn't what you want -- you want an error. So you should check that at least one of $c$ and $s$ is nonzero, and if both are zero, throw an exception or raise an error. (Listen to the guy with 50 years of experience here: you really DO want to do this.)

Comment: So is v the vector from the start point to the centre, and u is the vector from the endpoint to the centre?      EDIT or is it from the centre to the start and end points?

Comment: I just tried it and it works like a charm, but it always measures CCW, and I don't know how to find if I need to count it CCW or CW. Using this info I have, how do I find this? BTW i'm using C#, so it's using the ATAN2(Y,X) version thankfully xD

Comment: I was going to say "all vectors are measured FROM the center $C$ to some point $P$, and therefore computed by taking $P - C$." As for the second question, I guess you'd call it CW if the returned angle is between $-\pi$ and $0$. Or, if your code always returns $0$ to $2\pi$ answers, you say "if $\theta > \pi$ then (1) it's CW, and (2) $\theta = \theta - 2\pi$. But since you're just trying to make Bezier curves, all you need is start, end, start-tangent and end-tangent -- no CW or CCW stuff matters. One last point: Beziers cannot fit a circle perfectly. You have to use rational Bezier curves.

Comment: I don't need exact circles, but I can use cubic beziers to get almost exact approximations :)  . My issue is that the user can draw a road that almost makes a circle, perhaps say 350 degrees around. If I assume that any result that's greater than pi is CW, that would limit how far they can draw the road to 180 degrees surely? As soon as the angle is above 180 degrees, the road would flip.

Comment: If *all you have* is the start and the end point, how can you tell whether the user got to the endpoint via a 350-degree near-circle, or a 10-degree little arc? Both are possible ways to get the same input data to your Bezier-maker. If your data includes more than the start and end point, there might be some hope...but your question didn't seem to indicate this.

Comment: To find the start gradient (orange arrow on the diagram I shared) I have a point that gets recorded as soon as the user drags 10 units from the start point. If I calculate a vector from the start point to this point, I can use some "if" statements to see if it should be CCW or CW. It would be a bit hacky though, is there a more efficient way of finding this?

Comment: I found a solution! Alright so given the point I mentioned above, used to find the start point gradient (call it p2), I can also use it to find if I need a CW or CCW angle. If the angle from the centre to the start point to the point p2 is 90 degrees, the CW angle is wanted. however if the angle is 270 degrees, the angle wanted is the CCW one. http://imgur.com/Z0306f6

Comment: Sure, that should work OK. Best of luck.